# Improper feature Id attribute error

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio, feature

Hi I am getting `Improper feature Id attribute` error. I try to deploy a feature to a site using visual studio 2013. google cant help me so i ask here. this is my feature.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature Id="11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111"   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Scope="Site">
 <ActivationDependencies>
  <ActivationDependency
  FeatureId="11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111" />
 </ActivationDependencies>
 <ElementManifests>
  <ElementManifest Location="CP_Project1.xml"/>
</ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dependent feature and the dependee feature should have different GUIDs. Your code sample shows both features having same GUID. Here is an example:

```
<Feature Id="GUID1" Title="Feature Title" Description="Feature Description" Version="1.0.0.0" Scope="Site" Hidden="false"> <ActivationDependencies> <ActivationDependency FeatureId="GUID2" /> </ActivationDependencies></Feature>
```

Feature with GUID1 is a dependee feature and feature with GUID2 is a dependent feature and this will be a hidden feature.
Try looking for actual feature Ids and replace them in the above example.

Comment: Where can i find actual feature ids?

Comment: In the feature Designer. Or you can also click on the feature, press F4 and check it in properties window.